# Remove Transparent Background in Toolbar Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am using a toolbar in which the overflow menu options have a transparent background as shown in the image [transparent overflow menu in toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmhGB.jpg)[image]

I have tried editing the default theme and also tried out a custom theme as well as using a panel background option.
Could someone please let me know how to make the background of the overflow menu in the toolbar not transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your base theme as below one it should work as its working for me just compiled now. just add this

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```